# Want to retrieve records from mongodb in batchwise

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am trying to retrieve records from Mongodb whose count is approx up to 50,000 but when I execute the query Java runs out of Heap space and server crashes down.

Following is my code ;

```
 List<FormData> forms = ds.find(FormData.class).field("formId").equal(formId).asList();
```

Can anyone help me syntactically to fetch records in batchwise from mongodb.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use `asList` if your collection has >50 thousand results. Try reading this (in particular `hasNext`): http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the Java implementation has this but in the c# version there is a setBatchSize method.

Using that I could do

foreach(var item in coll.find(...).setBatchSize(1000)) {

}

This will fetch all items the find matches but it will not fetch all at once but ratgher 1000 in each batch. You code will not see this "batching" as it is all handled within the enumeration. Once the loop tries to get the 1001 item, another batch will be fetched from the mongodb server.

This should lessen heap space problem.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/

You could still have other problems depending on what you do within the loop, but that will  be under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching 50k entries doesn't sound like a good idea with any database.
Depending on your use case, you might want to change your query or work with [limit and offset](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Limit):

```
ds.find(FormData.class)
   .field("formId").equal(formId)
   .limit(20).offset(0)
   .asList();
```

Note that a range based query is more efficient than working with limit and offset.

Comment: This will fetch only 20 records i want to fetch all records in batch wise by putting some limit to it.